# Sql and php if not set

Tags: php, sql

I have a scrolling list with different names which i can choose from but if nothing is selected want all of them to be selected.

html:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <select name="names">
    <option selected disabled value="">Choose name</option>
    <option value="name1">Name 1</option>
    <option value="name2">Name 2</option>
  </select>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

php:

```
if(!isset($_POST['names'])) {
*what to put here if i want all if not set*
}
```

Sql:

```
WHERE name = '"($_POST['names'].'"
```

Comment: wheres the list of names ? in array in string  ?

Comment: Made some changes

Comment: How can `$_POST['names']` not be set? It will always be either `name1` or `name2`.

Comment: make a copy of values option in your server php and use from there

Answer (score 0):

Put the `WHERE` clause in a variable. If there are no names, make it empty.

```
if (isset($_POST['names'])) {
    $where = "WHERE name = '" . $_POST['names'] . "'";
} else {
    $where = "";
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM yourTable " . $where;
```

However, when a form has a `<select>` element, its value will always be sent in the POST, so `isset()` will always be true. Perhaps you should be checking `if (!empty($_POST['names']))`; if you have an empty default option, this will test if that option is selected.

Comment: If i don´t make choice it searchs the field called name if there are any fields that are empty and they are not and then i don´t get any rows at all

Comment: Are you using `isset()` or `empty()`?

Comment: If you don't make a choice, the parameter is set to an empty string, so `isset()` is true.

Comment: Did you read the last paragraph of the answer? Did you understand it?

Comment: Yes i used isset() and now it´s working. Thanks for the help